# Update file or folder Date Modified

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd

I need to update the "Date Modified" property of files and folders as they are copied from one location to the other so that "Date Modified" = Current System Time.  I have a PC with Windows 7, and I do NOT have administrative rights on it, so I can't install any custom utilities.  My current bat file uses XCOPY:

```
xcopy "\\sharepoint\dept\gis\Abandoned_Wire\*.*" "\\corp.dom\fs4\g1\OUTPUT\GRIDPROD\PDF\Maps\Abandon Wire Maps" /c /s /r /y /i
```

On my Windows XP box I use the "touch" command from UnxUtils, but I can't find an equivalent that's native to Windows 7.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

There is a very simple (though arcane) syntax to "touch" a file on Windows. (update the last modified timestamp)

If the file is in the current directory, all you need is:

```
copy /b fileName+
```

If the file is in some other path, then this works:

```
copy /b somePath\fileName+,, somePath\
```

However, it seems like you still would have a lot of coding to do, since I believe you only want to touch files that are copied.

The following is untested, though I believe it will work. I can't vouch for the performance. This solution requires 2 unused drive letters. I'm assuming K: and L: are available.

```
@echo off

:: map unused drive letters to your source and target paths
subst K: "\\sharepoint\dept\gis\Abandoned_Wire"
subst L: "\\corp.dom\fs4\g1\OUTPUT\GRIDPROD\PDF\Maps\Abandon Wire Maps"

:: replicate the folder hierarchy
xcopy K: L: /t

:: recursively copy and touch all files
for /r K: %%F in (*) do (
  xcopy "%%F" "L:%%~pnxF" /r /y
  copy /b "L:%%~pnxF"+,, "L:%%~pF"
)

:: release the temporary drive mappings
subst /d K:
subst /d L:
```

Comment: EDIT - changed COPY to XCOPY /R /Y to avoid problems with existing read-only files

Answer (score 6):

You could use `powershell`, which I believe is already installed on Windows 7 by default.  Add this line to your batch file to run a powershell command that updates the timestamp on all files named Abandoned_Wire*.*:

```
powershell.exe -command "ls 'folder\Abandoned_Wire\*.*' | foreach-object { $_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date }"
```

What that line is doing is simply:

`-command`: tells powershell to run the following command and return immediately

`ls`: list all matching files at the path specified

`foreach-object`: run the following block on each file that `ls` found

`$_.LastWriteTime = Get-Date`: for each file, set the `LastWriteTime` to the value returned by `Get-Date` (today's date and time)

Comment: Nice to see someone explain their answer.  Vote++.

Comment: I'll assume your ps code functions as advertised, I know next to nothing about ps. But it will "touch" *all* files, not just the files that were just copied. That might be a problem.

Comment: @dbenham: No, it will touch all files named "Abandoned_Wire*.*", which is what the OP had originally specified.  I see now that the question has been edited by you to add a \, but I'm not convinced that's what the OP meant.  I leave it to him/her to decide.

Comment: I see the source of the confusion. The original question had the line formatted as a quote instead of code. This resulted in some `"\\"` displaying as `"\"`, and `"\"` displaying as nothing. I reformatted the quote as code, and I'm pretty sure it represents the OP's intent. The paths and the question make more sense now. Your answer made more sense with the originally formatted question, but the edits do invalidate your answer. Even with the original question format, your answer is still susceptible to touching pre-existing files that did not come from the source.

Comment: Makes sense.  I've added the \ to my answer.  You're right, pre-existing files in the target folder will get touched as well.  That could be fixed by using powershell to perform the copying in the first place.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but this worked beautifully for me. All files in the folder have been updated to the current date/time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Robocopy** should be able to do this for you.  `robocopy` is a native tool included in Windows since Vista.

```
robocopy "\sharepoint\dept\gis\Abandoned_Wire" "\corp.dom\fs4\g1\OUTPUT\GRIDPROD\PDF\Maps\Abandon Wire Maps" /COPY:DA /S /IS
```

By default `robocopy` will copy `DAT`: Data, Attributes, and the Time stamps, but this can be controlled with the `/COPY` flag.

See [`robocopy /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for all the options.

Comment: That seems like it should work, but it is copying the source's timestamp for me.

Comment: @dbenham  Well that would be rather disappointing if it does not work as it says, but not all that surprising. **`:(`**  I just tried it myself, and it just ignored the `/copy` flag and performed a `DAT` copy.  Time to pull out the debugging!

Comment: If anyone has any insight into `robocopy`'s behavior go here http://stackoverflow.com/q/15212914/891976

Answer (score 0):

```
for /R %i in (\*.\*) do copy %i /B+ ,,/Y
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, it is always good to add an explanation to a code sample.