# Update timestamp of a directory on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, timestamp, filemtime

There is more or less well-known command line way to update the modification time of a file on Windows (described at [Update file or folder Date Modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208855/update-file-or-folder-date-modified), for example):

```
copy /b somePath\fileName+,, somePath\
```

According to my experience it does for a file, but does not for a directory (tested on WinXP - the command did not fail, but the directory modification time was not updated).

I tried to adjust it for a directory using such a trick that we can "point" to the directory using a special "NUL" filename on Windows. I tried two ways to do that, but they don't work as well:

```
copy /b somePath\fileName\NUL+,, somePath\filename\
copy /b somePath\fileName\NUL+,, somePath\
```

Could anyone explain me why it does not work or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which file system has the drive on which you used the copy command to update the last modification date of the folder? On all Windows the last modification date of a folder on NTFS partitions is updated if something is changed in the folder like creating a file and deleting it. But on FAT16 and FAT32 partitions the last modification date of a folder is not updated on something changes inside the folder.

Comment: Yes, it was NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any changes to the directory because the filename `nul` is not stored in the directory. Since the directory is not changed, its modification time doesn't change. You can do this instead:

```
type nul > somePath\fileName\SomeFileThatDoesNotExist.tmp && del somePath\fileName\SomeFileThatDoesNotExist.tmp
```

Comment: So, there is no way to do it without a real modification of the directory content? The example you wrote above I know of course :)

Comment: @AlexanderSamoylov, I think this falls under the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: @Squashman yes, but I agree with Alexander: having to actually create a file and then delete it is not "simple". If it was possible to do the same as with a file (appending an empty file to an existing file updates its timestamp) then it would be simpler. Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: IMHO, creating and deleting files is like an Introductory 101 class. You can't get much more simple than that.  The hack used to touch a file wouldn't be considered simple in my book.