# ffmpeg keep original file date?

Tags: ffmpeg, autohotkey

I use this batch to cut off the beginning 6 seconds of a bunch of mp4 files,creating new files, in Win7. It works great, but the output files' date is new. How do I keep original date? But I don't want to re-encode mp4 files, just too many of them, too slow. Appreciate any response.

for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -ss 6 -vcodec copy -acodec copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208855/update-file-or-folder-date-modified/15209302#15209302

Answer (score 3):

You can change the file date using the PowerShell:

```powershell
powershell (Get-Item -LiteralPath 'out.mp4').CreationTime = (Get-Item -LiteralPath 'in.mkv').CreationTime
powershell (Get-Item -LiteralPath 'out.mp4').LastWriteTime = (Get-Item -LiteralPath 'in.mkv').LastWriteTime
powershell (Get-Item -LiteralPath 'out.mp4').LastAccessTime = (Get-Item -LiteralPath 'in.mkv').LastAccessTime
```

In your case it will look like this:

```batch
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%a" -ss 6 -vcodec copy -acodec copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
    powershell ^(Get-Item -LiteralPath 'newfiles\%%~na.mp4'^).CreationTime = ^(Get-Item -LiteralPath '%%a'^).CreationTime
    powershell ^(Get-Item -LiteralPath 'newfiles\%%~na.mp4'^).LastWriteTime = ^(Get-Item -LiteralPath '%%a'^).LastWriteTime
    powershell ^(Get-Item -LiteralPath 'newfiles\%%~na.mp4'^).LastAccessTime = ^(Get-Item -LiteralPath '%%a'^).LastAccessTime
)
```

`-LiteralPath` is required if your file name/path contains any special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help,@mayudong, but I know nothing about powershell and could not understand that. Finally I got it through with AHK:

```html
SetWorkingDir g:\

#m::
Loop, %A_WorkingDir%\*.mp4
{
 if( InStr(A_LoopFileName,"news")=1 or InStr(A_LoopFileName,"today")=1  ){
  FileGetTime,mt,% A_LoopFileLongPath
  runwait,ffmpeg -y -i "%A_LoopFileLongPath%" -ss 8 -vcodec copy -acodec copy "g:\+temp\%A_LoopFileName%"
  FileSetTime,mt,g:\+temp\%A_LoopFileName%
 }
}
return
```